# Определить ширину view по максимальной ширине сиблинга

Tags: android, xml, view

Я динамически добавляю кнопки во фрагмент по вертикали. Как выровнять ширину этих кнопок по ширине максимально длинной кнопки? Ширина самой большой кнопки определяется по "wrap_content"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Группа родитель как wrap_content все элементы как match_parent

Comment: @Style-7, хм... Мне кажется, что так оно в 0 схлопнется. Возможно ошибаюсь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой код дал требуемый эффект:
Добавляем кнопки с параметрами

```
 final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        Button button_1 = new Button(this);
        button_1.setText("Лебедь");

        Button button_2 = new Button(this);
        button_2.setText("Рак");

        Button button_3 = new Button(this);
        button_3.setText("Щука");

        linearLayout.addView(button_1, params);
        linearLayout.addView(button_2, params);
        linearLayout.addView(button_3, params);
```

И сама разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```